# Facebook developers, friends access

Tags: facebook

I would like to develop a facebook application however i am unsure if facebook allows a developer to have access to a users friends list.

Answer (score 2):

You can get user's friends by issuing `GET` request to `<user_fb_id>/friends`. Read more here: [Graph API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends)

Answer (score 1):

facebook allows access to users' friends list and their info like username, profile pic, email-address,etc.
check out this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/
i hope it'll solve ur purpose.